# modify firestore access rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I restrict in firestore that only the user with a certain email can write to the database and only authenticated users can read? At the moment I have the rules like this, so that everyone can access the database:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if (true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, this is probably a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started Pay special attention once you get to the page with common scenarios: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics

Comment: for authenticated users there is an example but for a certain email there is not.